# Delete row in UITableView in conjunction with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to delete a row in a UITableView (PFQueryTableViewController). The object deletes in the class, but is only reflected in the table when I refresh the table. Here is the code I am using.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {


            [tableView reloadData];
        }];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it.

Instead of `[tableView reloadData]`, I've used `[self loadObjects]`.

However, the usual delete animation is not there.

Comment: spogebob92 did you ever find a way to get the animation for the row delete with Parse??

Comment: No I didn't, if you find a way, please report back :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to make all UI updates in main thread.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }];
}
```

}

Comment: Parse callbacks already happen on the main thread; that's not the issue